# open application on install android

Tags: android, installation

I am making an application but i don't want it to be on the Home Screen as a Launcher icon.  It holds Background Service.

Is it possible that when the user install the application it opens the screen automatically so that user could enter the Pin Code or password? But that does not need to be on the launcher icon?

Please Friends Guide

Answer (score 0):

Its possible man.. Just remove intent filter tag under tag activity in the manifest file.
Declare activity as listed below

```
<activity android:name=".CallIntents"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: So, how to start application ?

Comment: then how to start application when installed??